# Jquery tab and mixed HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: jquery

I’m using a tab design with multiple tabs. There is one tab that needs to work under HTTPS. After a user clicks on the tab I’m getting an error message “Access Denied” with jquery-1.4.2.min.js. jquery-1.4.2.min.js is being loaded by the parent page using HTTP. I tried loading another version of jquery-1.4.2.min.js using HTTPS in the TAB page but still get the error.

In IE I get “Access Denied”. In Firefox, I get no error message but the page doesn’t get displayed.

Do I need call the parent page again using HTTPS to make this work?

Comment: You are probably running into an issue with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of the browser since the protocols don't match. I don't have time for an answer but that might help your searching

Comment: In my experience, Firefox won't alert you to the switch from http to https once you approve it once.  IE will continue to alert you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use HTTPS in all cases or HTTP, it's like requests to different domains, AJAX will not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the parent needs to be https, and just call everything over https.

I would suggest that when someone clicks on the tab that requires https that you

```
var test = /https/.test(document.location.href);
if(!test){
 document.location.href = https://version of site
}
```

Basically, when they click on the tab, check to see if the parent is in https, if not, forward them to the https version of the site.